# Ethernet not working on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: networking, 22.04, internet, ethernet, wired

My ethernet wasn't working on Fedora. I tried many things, nothing worked. It was getting detected but not working. WiFi and USB tethering works fine. Ethernet works fine on windows (dual boot). So I did a clean resinstall from Fedora to Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. The issue still persists. The issue is there even in the Ubuntu Live USB. It doesn't make sense, I tried manual IPv4 configurations too, that also doesn't work. The issue has persistes for many days now. Please help.

Here are network logs from journalctl -u NetworkManager:
https://pastebin.com/jgKFMX4L

Comment: Your log shows a successful activation of the interface. Please [edit] your Question and show us `ip address;ip route`. Please do not respind via Add Comment. Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting

Answer (score 0):

Update: I solved it!

What worked for me was I found my ethernet controller was rtl8111/8168/8411 using the command `lspci` and I had to download r8168-dkms drivers and permanently add kernel boot parameters `r8168.aspm=0 r8168.eee_enable=0 pcie_aspm=off loglevel=3`