# Ethernet stops working on Always-On Computer Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: networking, 22.04, ethernet

We have a few computers showing information on the screen **24/7** for monitoring. After a few days (maybe a week) the **network stops working** - computer is connected via Ethernet. Everything works normally for a week after the computer is restarted.

We also have a few computers (same model) running Windows and there is no such problem - likely **not a application problem or a hardware issue**. These computers are also in different networks - likely not a network issue.

This problem is hard to debug as it happens only ever so often. Can anybody give any advice on what could be the problem? How would I debug this or try to find a fix?

I would like to fix the root of this problem, but obviously I could just run a cron job to restart the computer every so often or similar, however, I would like to avoid that.

Comment: Does it work if you disconnect and reconnect using the Network Manager app or the terminal? If this works, yo u may just do that with a cron job, rather than restart the computer. Does it work if you physically unplug and replug the Ethernet cable?

Comment: Look at the network logs with the terminal command: `sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl NetworkManager`.

Comment: I will definitely try all of these things, when I get the chance. Thank you

Comment: It looks like a more "low-level problem" to me. Restarting the network manager didn't help at all (from either the gui nor terminal); replugging the Ethernet cable didn't make a difference either.

I also looked at the network logs as @waltinator suggested, but am not really sure what I'm looking for: [https://pastebin.com/VmZHX6Tk](pastebin here). I'm sorry that the timestamps are in Czech, but it shouldn't be a problem (there are only 2 days anyway - 22nd Sep - the day the computer was setup, 2nd Oct - I'm guessing that's when it stopped working)

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1482676/ubuntu-22-04-3-lts-wired-network-connection-randomly-breaking-until-reboot and https://askubuntu.com/questions/1477022/ethernet-not-working-on-ubuntu-22-04-lts are possibly related to this.