# ubuntu 22.04 LTS ethernet not working

Tags: 22.04, ethernet, tethering

I have been using ubuntu 20 for sometime and shifted to 22. However, I have been constantly facing the ethernet connection issue.

This answers https://askubuntu.com/a/1477062/1370321
the issue; downloading the driver and adding it to kernel.

But it's not elaborated and I couldn't solve the issue.

Any help!

Comment: You put those boot parameters in `/etc/default/grub` on the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=` line, and inside the quotes. Then `sudo update-grub` and reboot